# How to account for different replicates?

Tags: regression

I am analyzing an experiment. I am particularly interested in the volume loss rate (or log volume loss rate) by pulse. Attached is the graph of one of the arms. It shows three replicates of the same arm. This arm is difficult because there is a rate in the beginning, then it suddenly changes to a different rate. After 44 pulses or so, each of the three replicates have somewhat similar rates, but are translated up or down. When I try to fit a line, you get the below.

I am trying to fit this line along with all the other arms as a single linear model. I am not sure how to account for the initial part that is very different and the different locations (translations up or down). The average rate is the goal.

Any thoughts? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is there any numerical value that can be assigned to distinguish between the different arms, such as a mass value or a length value? Anything that can distinguish between the different data sets can be used as part of the equation, which would change from the form "y = f(x)" to the form "z = f(x, y)".

Comment: Building on James Phillips' comment, you would have $log\_vol = f(pulse,other\_1,other\_2,...,other\_k)$. The others could be mass or length, for example.

Comment: These are three replicates of the same experimental setup. They should be identical- except for experimental error.  In an experiment replicates always get averaged (or combined somehow), you can't include it as a factor. If you include it as a factor, then you lose your measure of experimental error. This is why I need the average loss rate of all three, but the line isn't coming out right because of the first part, and the translations up or down.

Answer (score 1):

I extracted the data from your plot as top, middle, and bottom data sets. The best single equation I found to fit each of the three individual data sets was a non-linear double exponential, "y = a * exp(b*x) + c * exp(d*x)" as shown below.

I have also included a graphical Python fitter for this equation which has Python's scipy.differential_evolution genetic algorithm give initial parameter estimates for the non-linear solver, so that you do not need to supply them.

TOP dataset:
[image: top]

MID dataset:
[image: mid]

BOT dataset:
[image: bot]

Here is the Python auto-estimating nonlinear fitter and a screenshot of its output:

[image: screenshot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

text_data = '''172.2405 1.7533
168.7809 1.7595
165.5684 1.7719
162.8501 1.7802
159.3904 1.7843
157.1664 1.7905
153.9539 1.8008
150.2471 1.8050
148.0231 1.8215
145.3048 1.8215
140.6096 1.8339
139.1269 1.8442
135.9143 1.8442
132.2076 1.8566
129.7364 1.8752
126.7710 1.8876
123.8056 1.8917
120.3460 1.8897
117.8748 1.8979
114.4152 1.9165
111.4498 1.9227
108.4843 1.9207
104.2834 1.9351
102.3064 1.9537
99.8353 1.9661
96.6227 1.9620
93.9044 1.9744
90.6919 1.9785
87.4794 1.9909
85.0082 1.9950
81.7957 2.0074
77.8418 2.0136
71.9110 2.0302
69.4399 2.0405
66.7216 2.0550
62.5206 2.0632
60.0494 2.0777
57.8254 2.0860
54.1186 2.0963
51.6474 2.1045
47.4465 2.1190
44.7282 2.1293
41.7628 2.1500
38.3031 2.1893
35.8320 2.2223
32.8666 2.2450
29.6540 2.2450
27.1829 2.2698
22.9819 2.2616
20.5107 2.2822
17.7924 2.3008
14.5799 2.3277
12.1087 2.3380
9.1433 2.3607
5.6837 2.3690
2.7183 2.3855
-0.4942 2.4021'''

xData = []
yData = []
for line in text_data.split('\n'):
    xData.append(float(line.split()[0]))
    yData.append(float(line.split()[1]))

xData = numpy.array(xData)
yData = numpy.array(yData)


def func(x, a, b, c, d): # double exponential from zunzun.com "function finder"
    return a * numpy.exp(b*x) + c * numpy.exp(d*x)


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 50.0]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 0.0]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, 50.0]) # search bounds for c
    parameterBounds.append([-1.0, 0.0]) # search bounds for d

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

EDIT: Per my suggestion to you in the comments, here are the parameters and screenshot from using all extracted data for the three arms.

Fitted parameters: [  2.27108235e-01  -4.80761444e-02   2.15718006e+00  -1.82871829e-03]

RMSE: 0.108131518809
R-squared: 0.784349398626

[image: all]

Comment: Wow! You put a lot of effort into this. Thanks! Although I need to find a single line for all three. Really I just need the average rate. I mean I could fit three lines and take the average by hand, but this part of a larger linear model that would compare it to other rates.

Comment: Meh - I have everything semi-automated now, so there's not much work in - I mean yes, yes! I put a HUGE effort into it, that's what I mean, sure... Seriously, just fit all three data sets at once for the average rate.

Comment: The line above is the fit. It doesn't represent the data for the reasons in my original post. Not sure how to fix it, that's the problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include using all data to make a fit per my previous suggestion. See the "EDIT" at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I am going to see if I can get the rest of the data to fit this form, and maybe do some sort of hierarchal model? I'll see.